# Importing properties to soapUI

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I need to import properties to soapUI test case, the purpose is to send a random id with every amf call that's initiated.

I have prepared the id's in a notepad, im not good in groovy scripting and i got no idea as of how to call the values from the script and pass it over to the property table. I read a few scripts but they really dint help me out, I need a script that can read the values from the notepad and pass over the values to the property field in the test case.

This is the scenario im planning to execute; I have a set of functions, the main parameter for the calls is the user's id which have to be passed along every call.

This user id's are saved to a text file, what i need is that i should be able to call these values from the text file through soapUI's parameter definitions.

the value in the notepad will be of the format; big_12345

Answer (score 0):

This can be facilitated through SoapUI's Load Properties feature.

Start by clicking on your Project, and then the Test Case you need to import properties into. Once selected, in the bottom left corner of the screen, there's a tab for 'Custom Properties'. Select this tab, and click the 'Load Properties' button (it should be the second from the far right).

Browse and select the text file containing your properties and their values, in the following format:

NAME=VALUE

APPLE=123

BANANA=456

Check the 'Create Missing Properties' option, click okay, and the import should begin!

This selection from SoapUI's wiki may prove beneficial:

http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/working-with-properties.html

Comment: i tried the above steps mentioned, but soapUI only takes a particular id from the list, my list have these properties in it

id=id_1000053
id=id_1000020
id=id_1000022
id=id_1000040
id=id_1000041

soapUI only takes the last id from the list, cant find out why.
Are you sure that the free version of soapUI does this??

Answer (score 0):

I use this to set my id's, its based on the date so it always changes, and it is very usefull to avoid the duplicate request Id error.
This goes in a Groovy script that has to be executed before the test.

```
def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
def date = new Date()

def timestamp = sdf.format( date)
def seq = "ip:" + date.getTime()

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "id", seq )
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "timestamp", timestamp )
```

Then I set the property at the suite level by adding it to the custom properties.

To use the property in the request you place this in the value where the requestId goes

```
     ${=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("id")}
```

Comment: ill try out the same, can you just enlighten me on how to call the parameters from the property field in the teststep, i mean the values that i collect using the code above. im too bad in coding

Answer (score 0):

How random do you need the IDs to be? You can use something like `${=Math.random()}` in place of any parameter / field, and you will get a random value every time you run it.
If the ID needs to have a particular pattern, then could you clarify your question.

Comment: my plan is to send a random Id when the request call is made, im not really concerned about the order the parameters would be passed on. i found a few examples on as of how to do this but im too confused with the part of calling the parameters from the property field in the teststep.

Comment: Update your original question: show a real sample, explain what do you want.